# how to create a new column in pd using a conditional with strings?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, sorting

I have a column with over 30 different types of 'industry'.  I want to create a new column and also combine some of the 30 different types of 'industry' into a new name.  Basically for example I want to take finance and crypto and combine them into a new category called 'financial' or take travel, fitness, retail and make them 'consumer'.

I'm just having a hard time thinking if i should use an if/else or loc function?  or maybe just create a big dictionary?

I haven't yet tried anything since I've kind of overthought myself to death on this one.  Just looking for advice.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a simple task for `map` with mapping dictionary:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'industry': ['fin', 'crypto', 'test']})
mapper = {'fin':'financial', 'crypto': 'financial'}
df['industry'] = df['industry'].map(mapper).fillna(df['industry'])
```

Output:

| industry |
| --- |
| financial |
| financial |
| test |

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you would to create a new column depending on the value of the industry column

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
'industry': ['finance', 'crypto', 'fitness', 'retail', 'travel']},
 dtype={'industry':'category'}))

financial = ['finance', 'crypto']
consumer = ['finance', 'fitness', 'retail']

# Create a new column based on the conditions
df.loc[df['industry'].isin(financial), 'new_column'] = 'financial'
df.loc[df['industry'].isin(consumer ), 'new_column'] = 'consumer'
```